# Should tag spelling be standardized to US English?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request

I have noticed that some tags on this site are spelled with US English, while others are spelled with UK English. Examples:

#### UK English

- [ageing](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ageing) vs. aging
- [gelatine](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gelatine) vs. gelatin

#### US English

- [fertilizer](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fertilizer) vs. fertiliser
- [soy](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/soy) vs. soya

Should we concern ourselves with this inconsistency?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question has already been asked on the SOFU (Stack Overflow/Server Fault/Super User) trilogy of sites and the consensus of those communities is that any spelling is acceptable in questions but tag spelling should be standardized to US English.

> Q: Does SOFU have an accepted standard on language and spelling? Which is it?
>    A: For bodies, no. For tags, US-English.

<sup>(Source: [What should the standard spelling be - British or US?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23869/what-should-the-)standard-spelling-be-british-or-us))</sup>

Given the above, I suggest that [ageing](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ageing) be renamed [aging](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aging).

Comment: I've gone ahead and renamed that tag, and it's now a synonym as well.

Comment: @Riker Can you synonomize gelatine with gelatin?

Comment: Despite there being no 'gelatine' questions, I've merged them.

Answer (score 0):

We should probably also rename [gelatine](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gelatine) to [gelatin](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gelatin) for consistency as per the rationale in my [other answer](https://vegetarianism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/254/1236).